# pig shell setup: automatically executing pig scripts

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way to automatically run a pig script when invoking pig from command line?

The reason I'm wondering about this is that I have several import and define statements that I use constantly over and over to set everything up. Is it possible to define this collection of statements somewhere so that when I start pig, it will automatically execute those lines? I apologize in advance if this is something trivial that I missed from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can certainly do so from version 0.11 onwards.
You need to use `.pigbootup` file.

Here is a nice blogpost on setting up the `pigbootup` file 
http://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/pig-specify-a-default-script/

If you want to include Pig-Macros from a file you can use the `import` command
Take a look at http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#import-macros for reference